# Concatenating rows in CSV file Using islice

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Basically, I have a list which indicates the line number of the CSV file, and I want to concatenate rows that follows the list.

For instance, my list is `[0, 7, 10, 11, 27, 31]`

This means I want to concatenate my rows from line1 to line 7 into a single row.

Line 8 to 10 to a single row.

Line 11 to 11 (same line so it will simply do nothing)

Line 12 to 27

Line 28 to 31

I have tried using a while loop and islice from itertools. However, I only get the output of Line 1 to Line 7.
Here is my code.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('csvtest.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
        #row1 = next(reader)
    merged = []
    list = [0, 7, 10, 11, 27, 31]

    x=0
    while x < len(list):   
        for line in islice(f, list[x], list[x+1]):
                    #print line1
            line = line.rstrip()
            merged.append(line)
            x += 1
print merged #gives ['fsfs', 'sf', '1231', 'afsa', '', '', 'asfasfsaf;0'] which is lines 1 to 7
```

Would anyone let me know what happened to my while loop? Or is it a problem with the append list part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the code, basically you need to change how to implement `islice`.

Updating the answer on the basis of new information.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('output2.csv','wb') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)

    delimiter_list = []
    merged = []


    with open('csvtest.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for num, line in enumerate(reader, 1):
            line = (" ".join(line))
            if line.endswith(';0'):
                    #print 'found at line:', num
                delimiter_list.append(num)

    with open('csvtest.csv', 'rb') as f:
        x=0
        while x < len(delimiter_list)-1:
            row = []
            # islice(f,N) returns next N lines  
            for line in islice(f, delimiter_list[x+1]-delimiter_list[x]):
                line = line.rstrip()
                row.append(line)
            x += 1
            # add each row to final list
            merged.append(row)
    print merged

    writer.writerows(merged)
```